# Is it possible to auto scroll In Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

It is possible auto scroll in android? I want my layout to start scrolling when my user loads up the screen, is it possible to do without them having to touch the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, there is a default method to solve this. However the `ScrollView` class (you probably need a `ScrollView`, to make the content scrollable) has a method, which enables you to scroll smooth through the content:

[`smoothScrollBy(int,int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#smoothScrollBy%28int,%20int%29)

the first (x) value is the horizontal, and the second (y) value is the vertical scroll. You could use a background Thread to call this method with the desired parameters, until the end of your ScrollView is reached.